# \paragraph does not appear where it should

Tags: floats, positioning, sections-paragraphs

until now I think I have searched the whole internet, but without finding an answer. I hope this question is not embarrassing.

I have the following Latex Code:

```
 \subsection{Benutzeroberfläche}

\subsubsection{Öffentliche Sicht}

\paragraph{Fallunbezogene Sichten}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[!hbt]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{frontend-mockup/Web 1920 öffentlich – Alle Publikationen.pdf}
 \caption{Ansicht aller Publikationen in der öffentlichen Sicht}
 \label{fig:public-all-publications}
\end{figure}
\end{center}

\paragraph{F1a - F2a Suchen und Filtern}
\begin{figure}[!h]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{frontend-mockup/Web 1920 öffentlich – Suche.pdf}
 \caption{Suchen von Publikationen in der öffentlichen Sicht}
 \label{fig:public-search}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}[!h]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{frontend-mockup/Web 1920 öffentlich – Alle Publikationen gefiltert.pdf}
 \caption{Filtern aller Publikationen in der öffentlichen Sicht}
 \label{fig:public-filter-all-publications}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}[!h]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{frontend-mockup/Web 1920 öffentlich – Suche gefiltert.pdf}
 \caption{Filtern der Suche in der öffentlichen Sicht}
 \label{fig:pulic-fitler-search}
\end{figure}


\paragraph{F3a BibTeX generieren}
...
```

But my problem is, that \paragraph isn't positioned where it should be. It should be (as is the order in the Latex Code):

1. \subsection{Benutzeroberfläche}
2. \subsubsection{Öffentliche Sicht}
3. \paragraph{Fallunbezogene Sichten}
4. Figure
5. Etc. You get the point...

But that is not happening. See:

[image]

And on the next page it only gets weirder: (Each paragraph in the red box should have content)

[image: Each paragraph in the red box has content]

I am just frustrated at this point and would much appreciate your advice.

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Your concern here is more about the placement of the figures, not so much the `\paragraph`s. For that, add `\usepackage{float}` and use the `[H]` float specifier (see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764); duplicate). However, you may have to manually insert page breaks in order for the layout to match your requirements.

Comment: don't pace `center` around `figure`.  The `\paragraph` always appears where placed but you have surrounded the image with `\begin{figure}..\end{figure}` the only purpose of that environment is to allow the figure to be moved to help with page breaking.

Comment: The center around the figure was a desperate attempt to fix this...

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't figure placement but paragraph title placement!

Since `\paragraph` merges the title with the first line of the ensuing paragraph the title has to be held until the paragraph is seen, or something else forces it, like another `poaragraph`. In your case, you have no text at all between the paragraph titles (no "content"), so the `\paragraph` is delayed until *after* the figure.

You can fix this by using

```
\paragraph{F1a - F2a Suchen und Filtern}
\indent % start paragraph
```

Or use `\mbox{}` or `~` instead of `\indent`. The aim is to create some blank paragraph text.

You also have an error of `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` around your figures. Since you already use `\centering` inside the figure, just get rid of the `center` environment.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want your images to float, don't use the `figure` environment. To nevertheless be able to add a caption to your images, you can use the `\captionof` command from the `\caption`  package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove the demo onption in your actual document

\begin{document}

\subsection{Benutzeroberfläche}

\subsubsection{Öffentliche Sicht}

\paragraph{Fallunbezogene Sichten}
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{frontend-mockup/Web 1920 öffentlich – Alle Publikationen.pdf}
 \captionof{figure}{Ansicht aller Publikationen in der öffentlichen Sicht}
 \label{fig:public-all-publications}
\end{center}

\paragraph{F1a - F2a Suchen und Filtern}
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{frontend-mockup/Web 1920 öffentlich – Suche.pdf}
 \captionof{figure}{Suchen von Publikationen in der öffentlichen Sicht}
 \label{fig:public-search}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{frontend-mockup/Web 1920 öffentlich – Alle Publikationen gefiltert.pdf}
 \captionof{figure}{Filtern aller Publikationen in der öffentlichen Sicht}
 \label{fig:public-filter-all-publications}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{frontend-mockup/Web 1920 öffentlich – Suche gefiltert.pdf}
 \captionof{figure}{Filtern der Suche in der öffentlichen Sicht}
 \label{fig:pulic-fitler-search}
\end{center}


\paragraph{F3a BibTeX generieren}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You've made a change that will allow this to work, but you didn't explain it.  The real  problem is that `\paragraph` requires another argument.  Just providing one (which you did by removing the `figure` environment} will get rid of the "misplacement" of the heading, but doesn't lead to understanding.